# Qt/Qml no sound on Rapsberry Pi 3

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, qtmultimedia

im trying to play some audio on RPI using qml, but i get no sound. There are no errors nor warnings.

```
Audio {
    id: audio
    autoLoad: true
    autoPlay: true

    source: "file:///home/pi/piano.wav"
    muted: false
    volume: 1.0
    onPlaying: {
        console.log("audio::onPlaying volume = " + volume)
    }
}
```

onPlaying is called and I get

```
qml: audio::onPlaying volume = 0.009999999776482582
```

- For some reason volume is 0.001 and i have no idea why.

I also tried MediaPlayer instead of Audio and get same result:

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaplayer
    autoLoad: true
    autoPlay: true

    source: "file:///home/pi/piano.wav"
    muted: false
    volume: 0.5
    onPlaying: {
        console.log("mediaplayer::onPlaying volume = " + volume)
    }
}
```

//

```
qml: mediaplayer::onPlaying volume = 0.009999999776482582
```

I also tried to play video, and it's ok but without a sound. Other audio formats are not playable.

What can be the issue? I dont have any sound errors in logs and omxplayer is playing audio fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found was was the problem.

In my case redirecting all sound to hdmi using raspi-config was not enough.

You should edit /boot/config.txt ; set there hdmi_drive=2
and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, this post helped : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98952

Installing `gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me on Qt6.

```
 MediaPlayer {
    source: "music.wav"
    audioOutput: AudioOutput {
        volume: 1
    }
}
```